# Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound Neo4j Windows Desktop Version

Tags: windows, error-handling, neo4j, cypher, desktop-application

Hi I am using windows 10 and Neo4j Desktop Version.

I am trying to perform nlp by using the following Cypher query:

```
CALL ga.nlp.processor.addPipeline({
name:"pipeline_name",
textProcessor: 'com.graphaware.nlp.processor.stanford.ee.processor.EnterpriseStanfordTextProcessor',
processingSteps: {tokenize:true, ner:true, dependencies:true, relations:true, open:true, sentiment:true}
})
```

However I get this error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound
There is no procedure with the name `ga.nlp.processor.addPipeline` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.
```

After searching online I added the following packages in the .conf file and the .jar files in the plugins file:[image]

And added in the config file:

[image]

After the above procedure I get a new error:

[image]

What should I do to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After reinstalling it 3-4 times, somehow it worked. I cannot explain it.

I followed this procedure: https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-nlp to install the nlp pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Add this  to your conf file:

```
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted = *
```

Comment: This kills the database for some reason